# Types of bonds in a molecule

Tags: bond

For example in dinitrogen pentoxide, $\ce{N2O5}$, covalent as well as coordinate bonds (type of covalent bonds) are present, but it appears that it contains only covalent bond.

What is a proper method to find out which type of bonds are present in a molecule?

Comment: related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/21709/why-does-coordinate-covalent-bond-form

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Electrovalent bonds are easiest to identify. If a compound is made up of a metal and non-metal/non-metallic radical (like carbonate), then, 99.99% times, it contains electovalent bond. If a compound is made up of 2 or more non-metals/non-metallic radicals, then it contains covalent bond. Coordinate covalent bonds appear mostly with compounds containing Hydrogen element. To identify the coordinate covalent bonds, you can draw the branched structural formula of the compound and see if the shared pair of electrons are coming from the same molecule.

Comment: What are you even talking about? @Kartik Watwani Please don't accept such low quality answers