# Why does the compound formed after a coordinate bond have a net charge?

Tags: physical-chemistry, bond

Why does the molecule have net positive charge?
[image]

Comment: Because the particles _before_ the formation of the said bond had a net charge.

Comment: why not negative charge then?

Comment: Because they never had negative charge in the first place.

Comment: shouldn't positive charge of H get neutralised when it gets an electron? Also, what are the criteria for getting the total charge of the compound? Is it by adding formal charges? What is the formal charge of O after forming the coordinate bond?

Comment: It never _gets_ an electron for free. Instead, it starts to _share_ someone else's electrons.

Comment: Before you know a thing about formal charges, and even before you know a thing about _atoms_, you have to know that the **total charge is always conserved**. Now the total charge of $\ce{H2O}$ is 0, and the total charge of $\ce{H+}$ is +1 (we know that because it is written with that little $^+$). Just what their combined total charge might be?

Comment: +1, so every time a compound ionizes, is it because of coordinate bond?

Comment: No, this is **not** because of coordinate bond. The charge is conserved _no matter what_. Coordinate bonds are irrelevant here, as well as bonds of any other type.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I have feeling this is hopeless case here...

Comment: @IvanNeretin I finally understood it :)  Thanks for your patience

Answer (score 2):

Consider the formation of the given hydronium ion: $\ce{H2O + H+ -> H3O+}$ (also more correctly stated as the auto-ionization of water: $\ce{2H2O -> H3O+ + OH-}$)

The positive charge you're seeing indeed belongs to the whole molecule, as any reaction conserves charge both on the left and right side of the arrow.

However, this is not true in general. If a neutral molecule itself forms from neutral atoms, which involves a coordinate bond, then the molecule won't be charged.

Although, do note that the [distinction between normal covalent bond and coordinate covalent bonds is artificial](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/21709/why-does-coordinate-covalent-bond-form).

Answer (score 0):

The charges are produced only due to the nearness of the electrons with the nucleus of the respective atom.
Here the co-ordinate bonds produces charge because the electrons in this case is near the H atom which results in a partial positive charge on H that's why there is a charge overall in the compound.